# Refresh Table Contents When View Reappears

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, view

I am writing a note taking app, just for reference.  I have arrays set up, and a table that feeds off the arrays with the following code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

var tableData = ["Pancake Recipe", "Costume Party", "Camping Supplies"]
var tableSubtitle = ["Some Milk and some Flour", "Let's dress up like Jen", "Tenting with Lucy"]

class ViewController: UIViewController {



func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier:"cell")
    cell.textLabel!.text = tableData.reverse()[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = tableSubtitle.reverse()[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var listTitle = "Notes"
    self.title = listTitle

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = .LightContent
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    println(tableSubtitle)

}
```

}

A user creates a new title and subtitle for the cell on a different page, and these are added to the arrays (the tableData and tableSubtitle arrays).  I know the adding of the data works correctly, because when I watch the console it prints both the updated arrays perfectly.

When I then return to the main view controller, I am presented with an extra cell (as I wanted) but instead of the new content that I want, it is instead just a duplicate of the 'Pancake Recipe' cell.

Do I need to refresh the content of the cells when the view loads again?  If so, how can I do this?

Thanks :)

For reference, here is a picture of the Table View after data has been added to both the arrays twice, and I have then returned to the Table View, despite the fact both the arrays now contain two extra and distinct entries (checked using println(tableData) and println(tableSubtitle)

[image]

Comment: Can you add the code your using to add new cells. Then might be able to provide you with a more useful answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The provided code does not provide much information to find the issue, probably the issue will be with data adding code.

For refreshing the table view use:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    self.yourTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: How do I know what to replace 'yourTableView' with?  Sorry!

Comment: @Mydogmaxieboy: It's your tableview's outlet name, if you are using a `UITableViewController`, then `tableView` will be the name.

Comment: Just adding an IBOutlet for that like you said worked perfectly!  Thank you very much!  You genius you!